# Add table on ajax response

Tags: php, ajax

I want to add table on ajax response. But table is not showing on ajax response only contents displayed.

```
echo $result = "
                <tr>
                    <td> Rates</td>
                    <td style='font-size:small;'>words</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>CHF<td>
                    <td>".$_SESSION['calculate']['euro']."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>".$_SESSION['calculate']['filename']."</td>
                </tr>
            ";
```

ajax on complete

```
onComplete: function(file, response){
            //On completion clear the status
            status.text('');
            $('<table></table>').appendTo('#files').text(response);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('<table></table>').appendTo('#files').html(response);
```

You were inserting the table string as a text, not as actual html.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the result of a variable assignment (TRUE). Try removing the `$result =` and just echo the html.

```
echo "
                <tr>
                    <td> Rates</td>
                    <td style='font-size:small;'>words</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>CHF<td>
                    <td>".$_SESSION['calculate']['euro']."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>".$_SESSION['calculate']['filename']."</td>
                </tr>
            ";
```

Comment: its not working. Here is my ajax `onComplete: function(file, response){
    //On completion clear the status
    status.text('');
    $('<table></table>').appendTo('#files').html(response);
   `